# How to concatenate 2 string arrays w/o duplicate

Tags: arrays, string, duplicates, concatenation

Can you give me 2 algorithms how to make third array which values are unique, from 2 string arrays in Java or C#.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are talking about PHP (fix your tags please):

```
array_unique(array_merge($array1,$array2), SORT_REGULAR);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php

Answer (score 0):

c#

```
string[] c = a.Concat(b).Distinct().ToArray();
```